# RemoveStoryboard so that it animates back to original

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

I have the following code:

```
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>
  <BeginStoryboard Name="foo" Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeInCurrentStoryBoard}"/>
</DataTrigger.EnterActions>
<DataTrigger.ExitActions>
  <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="foo"/>
</DataTrigger.ExitActions>
...
<Storyboard x:Key="FadeInCurrentStoryBoard">
  <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="#75BAFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MainText"/>
...
```

The problem is that removing the storyboard is immediate, but I would like to have a 0.2 delay back to the original values. I do not see any properties to set the removal duration?

Comment: Actually, @TylerD87 answer is probably true, you want to reset the state of something, instead of trying to destroying the storyboard. At least that is what you make it sound like. True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to put another storyboard in **ExitActions** called FadeOutStoryboard that performs the opposite action rather than **RemoveStoryboard**.

**RemoveStoryboard** is a way of freeing up memory when a storyboard is no longer needed rather than reversing the effects of a previous animation.

Comment: You are correct. The other answers are nice, but this is what I need. I had suspected that, but was hoping there was a more unique way of handling it

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to make your own class that inherits from ControllableStoryboardAction (like the RemoveStoryboard action does) and add a delay property to that. Then when it is invoked, respect the delay with a timer, and when the timer finishes, remove the storyboard.

The RemoveStoryboard class (using JustDecompile) looks like this:

```
public sealed class RemoveStoryboard : ControllableStoryboardAction
{
    public RemoveStoryboard()
    {
    }

    internal override void Invoke(FrameworkElement containingFE, FrameworkContentElement containingFCE, Storyboard storyboard)
    {
        if (containingFE != null)
        {
            storyboard.Remove(containingFE);
            return;
        }
        storyboard.Remove(containingFCE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you could simply use the [AutoReverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.autoreverse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property on the `ColorAnimation` and set it to true.

This will make 1 repetition of the animation include both the initial color change, and then the reverse of that, meaning it will transition back to the original value over the same duration.

```
<ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="True"..
```